# My app resets data when it is minimized

Tags: java, android

i made an android game once i minimize it,
it resets data and refresh the timer like you started the game from the scratch 
how can i make it Don't do this

i think the problem is on the OnStart function

```
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Reset score
    Configs.score = 0;
    scoreTxt.setText(String.valueOf(Configs.score));


    // Set progressBar and start the gameTimer
    pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.gbProgressBar);
    progress = 0;
    pb.setProgress((int) progress);
    startGameTimer();


    // Get a random circle for letters
    Random r = new Random();
    randomCircle = r.nextInt(Configs.circlesArray.length);


    // Reset taps count
    tapsCount = -1;


    // Get a random word from words string-array
    getRandomWord();
}
```

Comment: Read about the activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onStart` is called every time the app starts. `onCreate` on the other hand, is only called when the app starts or after the activity process has been killed and restarted. Usually the last scenario means after `onStop` is called and the activity process is killed, but it isn't destroyed yet.

Move that code to onCreate, otherwise it calls that every time the app is reopened which resets it

Comment: @Tim [It's `onStop`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), not `onDestroy`. If onDestroy is called, the next time it creates itself is a new instance of the app and there it's natural to create it anyways (and obvious, no need to mention that)

Comment: you got it backwards

Comment: @TimCastelijns backwards how?

Comment: onCreate is only called after onStop in case the app process is killed when the activity is stopped but not yet destroyed. You can see it in the diagram. onCreate is also called when you start an activity that was previousy destroyed/finished

Comment: So what do you recommend for me?

Comment: is there any place could i store my data and get it back after restart?

Comment: Look into data saving for that. Moving it out of onStart and into onCreate will solve a lot of problems though, it is rare that the process is killed because it was closed (unless specified by the OS)